# Running a Meteor app in an iframe from a different domain

Tags: iframe, meteor

After weeks of work I was now finally ready to deploy my app just to find out that meteor doesn't seem to run in an iframe. It works fine when the top level window and the iframe run on the same domain, but not when the domains differ. The error I'm getting on Chrome is:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Access to 'sessionStorage' is denied for this document.
```

After that error, the initialization of Meteor seems to stop and not even `Meteor` itself will be defined.

After some digging, I found this reference and explanation: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#user-tracking
: "**Blocking third-party storage**
User agents may restrict access to the localStorage objects to scripts originating at the domain of the top-level document of the browsing context, for instance denying access to the API for pages from other domains running in iframes."

The problem is not specific to my app. You can take any of the demo apps in the meteor gallery and try to embed them in another page with an iframe and you'll see what I mean.

Is there any way around this?

*Edit 2014-01-07:*
I have tried wrapping some of the places where exceptions are thrown in try-catch blocks, but got the impression that that was crippling meteor too much, such that it wouldn't properly initialize for a different reason.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it should be a problem if your container page and your Meteor app are served from the same domain and port. Is that not the case?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Facebook canvas apps run in a separate iframe, which would produce exactly this behaviour, of which I was not previously aware.  This is therefore a useful question, but I don't know how to answer it at present.

Comment: @MattPatenaude: yes, as I said, it works fine when the domain is the same, but not when they differ. And no, for my application the domains are not the same.

Comment: Did you add [browserpolicy](http://docs.meteor.com/#browserpolicy) to your app?

Comment: @DavidWeldon no I didn't. I just tried this, adding the package and setting `BrowserPolicy.framing.allowAll()`, but that didn't change anything. If I remove this `allowAll()` statement again, then I get a different error, saying explicitly that the meteor app doesn't want to be framed. So now I removed the package again.

Comment: Christian, how does the application now it is framed? Using referrer? If yes, [referrer killer](https://code.google.com/p/referrer-killer/) exists for links and images, maybe there will be some for iframes too.

Comment: @Tomas: thanks, but that's not the problem. The meteor app doesn't itself care about being in an iframe, it is the top window that seems to dislike the fact that the iframe app wants to access the localStorage and sessionStorage. If there was a way to ensure that the iframe used a separate storage, that could be a solution, but the link you provided doesn't seem to accomplish that.

Comment: @ChristianF I've added a working sample below. Even though I am not sure what your specific problem is at this point, we should be able to deconstruct your set up to find what's blocking the policies from taking effect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce the specific issue you're having, but here are the steps I followed in order to get it working. Perhaps we can deconstruct it from there and figure out what the error is.

I created a blank application:

> meteor create testapp

then I added the browser-policy module:

> meteor add browser-policy

Then I edited testapp.js to make it use the Session:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return Session.get( 'welcome_text' );
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
        Session.set( 'welcome_text', 'Hello: ' + Math.random() );
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

  BrowserPolicy.framing.allowAll();

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

I created two nginx virtual hosts:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name test1.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

}


server {

    listen 80;
    server_name test2.com;

    location / {
        alias /websites/test2.com
    }

}
```

test1 is the meteor app and test2 is the iframe.

For test2, I created /websites/test2/index.html:

```
<iframe src="http://test1.com">
```

Then I added test1.com and test2.com to my hosts file and started the meteor app.

I went into http://test2.com on the browser, and everything works as expected. It looks like you've tried these steps more or less, but your application or server stack may have other components that are interfering with browser-policy.

I'd start by updating your question to include the request and response headers for the meteor app. Also, is your meteor app running behind a proxy?

Comment: thatjuan: this may seem silly, but you are right! It was a none-issue. Given your failed attempt to reproduce it, I went back and checked whether it had anything to do with the security settings in my browser. As I was creating a work-around using a REST API and cookies, I had noticed that my browser was blocking third-party cookies by default. This, as it seems, is also interpreted as blocking access to local- and sessionStorage (even though this is not stated in the Chrome settings). Thank you very much for taking the time to try and reproduce it. Clearly you were the first.  Well deserved!

Comment: @ChristianF cool, I figured it had to be something else because I have a production app running iframed on different domains. Glad it's solved :)

Comment: You, sir, are a savior. Finally fixed my problem!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the short answer to your question is no. I don't think there's a way to manipulate session variables through an iFrame. I think it's a security thing. If you give the reason why you need an iFrame and/or its context, I could try to come up with a solution that works around it, but I don't think it can be done with iFrames alone.

EDIT: Based on what you've said, it sounds like you need an API. The package I'd suggest for this is called [RestStop2](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/reststop2), which allows you to build easy RESTful APIs with Meteor. Check it out.

Comment: Imagine facebook ran on meteor and they'd like to offer some real-time data integration via an iframe on other cites, say, to show activity such as "liking" of your friends on a non-facebook page in real-time. That's the kind of scenario I'm interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Yes, I am now, as an alternative, considering just writing an API (using iron-router). But that's not ideal for what I'd like to do, and I'm sure I'm not the last person to try to run a meteor app in an iframe. So my question still stand.

Comment: I don't think it's possible due to the Session variables and the like. Sorry.

Comment: Cookies can be manipulated in an iframe so long as the browser doesn't block third-party cookies. So if Session variables are stored in cookies, that shouldn't be an issue. The documentation doesn't anything whether they are using localStorage or cookies for this.

Comment: Session variables are typically stored in the `Session Storate`, not in the cookies. Cookies would be a good alternative, however. Check out this cookie package from atmosphere: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/cookie

Comment: Yes, but it's not up to me to decide or configure whether or not Meteor will use cookies or `localStorage`/`sessionStorage` for its Session variables. The other question is where minimongo stores/caches its data.